# Running Wordpress PHP from command line - specifically for Plesk scheduled task

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line, plesk

I need to develop a script using Wordpress PHP that will run with the Plesk Scheduled task.  I've seen a few topics with this on stackoverflow and the web, but I can't seem to get the wordpress or script to work.  I'm fairly new to this, so I need a good step-by-step guide.

Basically, I want to run a PHP Script using the command line. (what's the command to do this?... I had "php -q /path/to/file.php" but not sure if that's it.)

Secondly, with this script, I need to be able to use Wordpress commands such as query_posts, add_post_meta, get_post_meta, etc.

I've seen elsewhere that I need the following at the top of the php file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$_SERVER = array(
  "HTTP_HOST" => "http://example.com",
  "SERVER_NAME" => "http://example.com",
  "REQUEST_URI" => "/",
  "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
);


require_once('/wp-load.php');
require_once('/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Is that it, or do I need more?  I assume I can place the PHP script in my root Wordpress directory and run it from there?

I've got the entire PHP part working, and can run it if I include it in a Wordpress page and simply load that page.  So I know the Wordpress part works.

I just need that other portion to get it working with the scheduled tasks.
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's it. Actually, all you need to do is set `HOST_NAME`.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but it's still not working.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you run it straight from the command line, without a cron task?

Comment: You know, it might be my permissions or the server configuration.  Is there a simple command I can test the Scheduled Task with?  Perhaps something that will email me if it works?

Comment: After looking at it further, it looks like I need to do some server configs.  Then it should work!  Thanks for your help!